# SQL return multiple rows from one record

Tags: sql

This is the opposite of reducing repeating records.
SQL query to create physical inventory checklists
If widget-xyz has a qty of 1 item return 1 row, but if it has 5, return 5 rows etc.
For all widgets in a particular warehouse.

Previously this was handled with a macro working through a range in excel, checking the qty column. Is there a way to make a single query instead?

The tables are FoxPro dbf files generated by an application and I am outputting this into html

Comment: The answer to this question is highly dependent on the datbase platform that you're using.  SQL Server?  Oracle?  Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL 2005/2008, take a look at

```
CROSS APPLY
```

What I would do is CROSS APPLY each row with a sub table with as many rows as qty has. A secondary question is how to create that sub table (I'd suggest to create an xml string and then parse it with the xml operators)
I hope this gives you a starting pointer....

Starting with

```
declare @table table (sku int, qty int);
insert into @table values (1, 5), (2,4), (3,2);
select * from @table;

sku         qty
----------- -----------
1           5
2           4
3           2
```

You can generate:

```
with MainT as (
    select *, convert(xml,'<table>'+REPLICATE('<r></r>',qty)+'</table>') as pseudo_table
    from @table 
)
select p.sku, p.qty
from MainT p 
CROSS APPLY 
(
    select p.sku from p.pseudo_table.nodes('/table/r') T(row)
) crossT


sku         qty
----------- -----------
1           5
1           5
1           5
1           5
1           5
2           4
2           4
2           4
2           4
3           2
3           2
```

Is that what you want?
Seriously dude... next time put more effort writing your question. It's impossible to know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Using the idea to create a table with as many rows as qty, I tried something like this, and then do a query similar to this:

SELECT widgets.SKU
FROM widgets INNER JOIN RowAmts ON widgets.QTY=RowAmts.qty;

However the prospect of creating a giant table with 100 rows of 100 or 99 rows of 99 of rows just seems wrong. Or is it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating an xml string and using xml parsing functions to generate a counter as Nestor has suggested, you might consider joining on a recursive CTE as a counter, as LukLed has hinted to:

```
WITH Counter AS
(
    SELECT 0 i

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i + 1
    FROM Counter
    WHERE i < 100
),
Data AS
(
    SELECT 'A' sku, 1 qty
    UNION
    SELECT 'B', 2
    UNION
    SELECT 'C', 3
)
SELECT * 
FROM Data
    INNER JOIN Counter ON i < qty
```

According to query analyzer, this query is much faster than the xml pseudo-table.  This approach also gives you a recordset with a natural key (sku, i).

There is a default recursion limit of 100 in MSSQL that will restrict your counter.  If you have quantities > 100, you can either increase this limit, use nested counters, or create a physical table for counting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table with number from 1 to max(quantity) and join your table by `quantity <= number`. You can do it in many ways, but it depends on sql engine.

Comment: is there a simple example of a join like this I could refer to?

Comment: FoxPro tables and usually constructing stuff in mssql or access first, then I reproduce what works in a webpage

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using dynamic sql.

Comment: access and mssql, but the tables are vfp

Comment: That will just add a new level of complexity to the problem.